# DateTime:createFromFormat creates wrong year and month from date

Tags: php, date

Passing the following date into the method: `1/13/2016 10:18:20` gives the following `2017-01-01 10:18:20`

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y H:i:s', $row->last_updated);

echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create format like below because there is no month with 13

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y H:i:s', $row->last_updated);
echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: My bad. Mixed up the order.